# Fowl Perpetrators Caught as Robberies Add Up

Tags: knowledge

After several years at Private Eye Academy, Joey Solvesalot finally earned his detective license and was looking forward to solving some cases. So he decided to settle in the infamous Problem City to start his career. After successfully moving in without a problem, Joey decided to go to the police headquarters to get some background on the type of cases that occurred in the past. While reading through the cases on the computer, one in particular caught his eye:

> **Case Title**: Fowl Perpetrators Caught as Robberies Add Up 
>   Date of Incident: ??-??-???? 
>   Incident: Robbery 
>   ...

He turned to an officer nearby, "Why is the date of incident incomplete?"

Officer Jenny glanced over and said, "Hmm, we digitized our old cases a few years ago but some of the handwriting was illegible."

"Ah I see," Joey murmured as he continued to look over the report.

> ...
>   **Offenders:**
>   Name     Sex Age DOB
>   Valentine, Holly F   22  April 5, XXXX
>   Winters, Jack     M   26  August 20, XXXX
>
> **Narrative**
>   Avy Ian (52), a lover and collector of birds-related items, reported several cases of theft on her property over the past month. On the first Tuesday of the month, she noticed that her set of seven stone swans in her backyard near the pond was missing (estimated \$3500 total). Ten days later, she found the door to her chicken coop ajar and three hens missing. A week later, she discovered a broken window and her set of four glass songbirds (estimated \$10000 total) gone. To prevent any further thefts, we made sure there was at least one officer on lookout at all times. Six days later we caught Holly Valentine and Jack Winters trying to make off with six goose-egg sized jewels (estimated \$25000 each). Looking into their residence, we recovered the seven stone swans and four glass songbirds. We found feathers that presumably came from the stolen hens, but could not find said hens.
>   ...

Once Joey finished reading, he smiled and said, "Are we allowed to edit this? I figured out the date!"

What day was the robbery (month and day) and why?

---

This is the first puzzle I've ever made, so <strike>please don't hurt me</strike> please feel free to suggest improvements!

Comment: Congratulationss on your first puzzle!  A well-put-together story!  (I can't comment on the puzzle itself, because I don't know the solution yet...).

Comment: I just thought about this again and have a question. Could Joey really figure out the date?
If it's because of the type and amount stolen goods and the song It would be funny, if the date would match. But with a little more criminal energy I could steel everything listed on any day.
Or is there a pure logical way to get the date, Joey could come up with?

Comment: In a strictly logical sense, I don't think it is possible to figure out the date with these details alone. However, there is a date that stands out from all of the information provided in the report, and that is the date i'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2nd guess

> December 25th

because

> 'Add Up' in the puzzle title refers to adding up the 2 other dates (DOBs) found in the puzzle to obtain the solution date. April (4) + August (8) = **December** (12).  5 + 20 = **25**

First guess

> December 27th (the 3rd day of Christmas)

because

> The thieves still had the four glass songbirds (calling birds) to be given starting on the 4th day of Christmas (December 28th) but not the three (French) hens which are to be given starting on the 3rd day of Christmas.

Comment: Very nice observation, but I'm afraid you went deeper than I planned :P. Even if I didn't mention anything about the hens in the end, you can still find the date.

Comment: Good find! This was the solution I was looking for :) But can you (or someone) find _all_ the hints I put in?

Answer (score 2):

Was it

> December 25th?

Because

> Each of the numbers of bird-related things stolen relate to 12 days of Christmas (3 French Hens, 4 Calling Birds, 6 Geese A-Laying, 7 Swans A-Swimming). Also there are 23 days between the first robbery and the last, which means it's possible for it to be Christmas.

I feel like my explanation is on the right track, but the jump to the answer is a bit tenuous.

Comment: You are on the right track, but there is definitely a more concrete step that can be taken to arrive at the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

If Victor is on the right Track I'm probably not but I'll try anyway:
My answer lies on the premise that "past month" means it's not the month the report was written... (sorry If I am wrong there and with past month you meant the last ~30 days I'm not a native English speaker)

Answer:

> 1st March

Explanation:

> Her first Discovery was on the first Tuesday of a month so it must be the 6th Or less.

After that

> 10 days later <= 16th the three hens were missing.

After that

> A week later <= 23th there was the brocken window.

After that

> 6 days later <= 29th the thiefs were caught and the report was written.

So in conclusion

> Since the report was written a month after the one with the robbery it has to be "March the 1st" because only February has less than 29 days

Don't be irritated by the "after that" I just don't get how to make a multirow spoiler.

Comment: Nice idea, but by "past month" I simply mean within the last ~30 days. There are more clues scattered across the case report than just the number of days between thefts!